# What is the difference between SASL and SASL PLAIN in Smack?

Tags: android, xmpp, smack, asmack, sasl

I'm working with something about IM. It involves XMPP.
I develop a app on Android, so I used aSmack. 
I want to log in google talk, and here (linked below)

https://developers.google.com/talk/open_communications

says google talk only support SASL PLAIN.
but when I search in the INTERNET, many people says google talk don't support the SASL
so this code is needed:

```
    connectionConfig.setSASLAuthenticationEnabled(false);
```

I am confused; who can tell me which is right or the differences between SASL and SASL PLAIN?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[**SASL** is a framework and protocol for authentication](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4422) that meant to be embedded into other protocols so that the libraries can be re-used.

[**SASL PLAIN** is a specific authentication mechanism](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4616) that you can use over SASL.

There are a bunch of [other SASL mechanisms](http://www.iana.org/assignments/sasl-mechanisms/sasl-mechanisms.xml) defined with various degree of support throughout protocols, servers and clients.  The main ones in use in XMPP is PLAIN, DIGEST-MD5 (mandatory in [the old XMPP RFC](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3920)) and [SCRAM-SHA-1](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5802) ([mandatory](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6120#section-13.8.1) in [the new XMPP RFC](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6120)).

Anyways, to answer your question:

If you disable SASL, then Smack will probably use what's called [legacy authentication](http://xmpp.org/extensions/xep-0078.html).  This might appear to fix things if you don't encrypt your connection with TLS, as many servers don't allow PLAIN over unencrypted connections.

Comment: a thousand thanks for your help，it helps me a lot.as you say,if I set the TLS mode is REQUIRED,whether it means I don't need the disable SASL code?

Comment: A good standard XMPP stream will first encrypt using TLS, and then authenticate using SASL.